# qplot - legend text in italics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a plot:

```
p = qplot(distance, Recombination, data = forplot, colour = factor(Species), size=I(4))

p + labs(title="Effective Recombination", x="Distance Categories", y="Effective Recombination Ratio", colour="Species") + ylim(0,0.022)
```

[image: Screenshot of plot so far]

However, I need the legend names (s. mimosarum and s. africanus) to be in italics. How do I do that? I have experimented with using expression and fontface, but I cannot get anything working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try sth like that

```
p + theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

Comment: I have a similar question but would like to put in italic only `some letters of the title of the legend`. In addition, do the same in the `xlab` and `ylab`. In the above example, I would like to get something like this:  S. _africanus_. Any ideas?